# Google SlidingTabsBasic with error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to see how this sample was done but I've got errors on Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) for Linux.

sourcecode: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SlidingTabsBasic

Error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex 
files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;   MainActivity        
Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

Could someone shed some light, please?

Comment: That project uses Gradle. is your Eclipse setup to use Gradle? You can easily import it with Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks. Downloading Android Studio since importing and opening projects with Eclipse seems to be a hassle.